# User right to only be able to add machines to an Active Directory domain

Tags: windows, active-directory

I know that to be able to add a machine to AD a user need domain rights. I would like to know if is it possible to give a user only the right to add a machine to AD but without the rest of the rights derived from been a domain admin.

In few words I would like to have only a user with the right to add computers to AD

Comment: From TechNet: `Add workstations to domain` This security setting determines which groups or users can add workstations to a domain.
 This security setting is valid only on domain controllers. By default, any authenticated user has this right and can create up to 10 computer accounts in the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a User can join 10 Machines to Active Directory without being a Domain Admin.
You have probably deleted this already.

You can manually grant this permission to users by adding the ***"Add workstations to a domain"*** permission in Active Directory.

Have a read here for more info: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976452.aspx